# Realtime Update with Jquery, AJAX,PHP & Arrays

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I'm trying to learn Jquery/AJAX using an array to execute and update code on different elements within a single function.

Below, I'm trying to update the DIVs with the number of people logged into the site, and the total currency in circulation. The script will update every few seconds.

Can anyone help me correct my syntax or at least tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateStats(stat)
{
    var stat = ["online","money"];

    var url = "online.php";

    $.each(stat,function(){

    $.post(url,{stat: stat} , function(data) {

        $("#" + this).html(data);       
    })

    })  
} 

setInterval('updateStats("updateStats")', 2000);
</script>


<body onLoad="updateStats(stats);">

<div id="online"></div>
<div id="money"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php

if($_POST['stats']=='online')
{
    $result= $mysqli->query("SELECT loggedin FROM accounts WHERE loggedin !=0");
    echo $result->num_rows; 
} 

elseif($_POST['stats'] == 'money')
{
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT sum(money) AS totalMoney FROM users");
$getData = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo number_format($getData['totalMoney']);

}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['stats']` / `{stat: stat}` stats != stat

Comment: What is it not doing currently, or what isn't working about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
function updateStats(stat)
{
    var stat = ["online","money"];
    var url = "online.php";

    $.each(stat, function(i, key){
       $.post(url, {stats: key}, function(data) {
          $("#" + key).html(data);       
       });
    });
}
```

Please also note the `stats` parameter in plural.

Comment: Would you accept this as your answer? in the check in your left.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$("#" + this).html(data);
```

`this` in that situation refers to a different `this` than what you are expecting. Try this instead:

```
$.each(stat,function(i,str){
    $.post(url,{stats: str} , function(data) {
        $("#" + str).html(data);       
    });
});
```

**Update** Fixed param name as per Rory's comment.

Comment: This would fire N number of post requests to the server, since you're embedding it in a loop.

You should send *one* request to the server, passing up the array of `stat`

Comment: @Atticus in an ideal situation yes, but sometimes the service can't accept an array and you can't change the service.